# List accessing in Python

Tags: python

I have a two list like this

```
Nodelist1=[[['B', 10], ['IN', 1000]], [['C', 15], ['OUT', 1001]], [['F', 30], ['IN', 1100]]]
Nodelist2= [[['G', 20], ['IN', 1000, 'OUT', 1111]], [['D', 25], ['INWARD', 1]]]
```

What I am trying to do is I am comparing these two lists like this

```
if len(Nodelist1[i][1])==len(Nodelist2[j][1])
```

If condition is true then I want to remove `Nodelist1[i][0]` which is `['B', 10]` and from `Nodelist1` and `Nodelist2[j][1]` which is `['D', 25]` from `Nodelist2`.

Then I should have

```
Nodelist1 as [[['C', 15], ['OUT', 1001]], [['F', 30], ['IN', 1100]]]
Nodelist2 as [[['G', 20], ['IN', 1000, 'OUT', 1111]]]
```

My code is like this:

```
   if len(Nodelist1)>len(Nodelist2):
      for i in range(len(Nodelist1)):
         for j in range(len(Nodelist2)):
            if len(Nodelist1[i][1])==len(Nodelist2[j][1]):
                if Nodelist1[i][1]==Nodelist2[j][1]:
                    Nodelist1.remove(Nodelist1[i])
                    Nodelist2.remove(Nodelist2[j])  
                else:
                    Nodelist1.remove(Nodelist1[i])
                    Nodelist2.remove(Nodelist2[j])
```

It gives me an **error:**

```
if len(Nodelist1[i][1])==len(Nodelist2[j][1]):
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `range`?

Comment: What else can be used to iterate over and achieve the result?

Comment: I'm not really seeing the logic here, why would `[['B', 10], ['IN', 1000]]` be removed from `Nodelist1` and why would `[['D', 25], ['INWARD', 1]]` be removed from `Nodelist2`?  This doesn't seem to match your description since those elements are completely different.

Comment: @F.J: if len(Nodelist1[i][1])==len(Nodelist2[j][1]) then I want to remove which matches

Comment: Okay, but `Nodelist1[i][1]` would be `['IN', 1000]` when `i` is `0`, and `Nodelist2[j][1]` would be `['INWARD', 1]` when `j` is `2`.  These are not equal.

Answer (score 5):

You are removing elements from a list while looping through it. So when you are moving to the end of the list, there are not enough elements. And the index accessing will raise an IndexError.

Comment: Right. Also, he/she is skipping every item in the list that follows a removed item.

Comment: Iterate backwards: `for i in range(len(Nodelist1)-1,-1,-1)` and `for j in range(len(Nodelist2)-1,-1,-1)`

Comment: @Jamie: The problem is my lists can change next time, In this case iterating bachward will work but not in other cases

Comment: I think at least you should make two new lists. And then you can loop through the original lists and removing elements from the copies.@user2592166

Answer (score 1):

It is rather bad idea to remove items from list iterating the way you do, e.g.

```
for i in range(len(Nodelist1)):
    pass
```

You could do something like this:

```
if len(Nodelist1)>len(Nodelist2):
    # store indexes of items to remove
    list1_to_del = []
    list2_to_del = []
    for i, item1 in enumerate(Nodelist1):
        for j, item2 in enumerate(Nodelist2):
            if len(item1) == len(item2):
                list1_to_del.append(i)
                list2_to_del.append(j)
             else:
                pass # not sure of your intensions and indentation

    # filter lists
    if list1_to_del:
        Nodelist1 = [item for i, item in enumerate(Nodelist1) if i not in set(list1_to_del)]
    if list2_to_del:
        Nodelist2 = [item for i, item in enumerate(Nodelist12) if i not in set(list2_to_del)]
```

But solution is somewhat clumsy:/

Comment: This is also a bad idea, you won't get index errors but you will skip elements.  Take a look at the following code: `x = [1, 2, 3]; for i in x: x.remove(i)`.  After this `x` will be the list `[2]`, not empty as you would expect.

Comment: I want to remove elements in else also as they still have same number of elements inside

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use `for i in range(len(your_list))` while you could simply do `for val in your_list` (or enumerate). But that is not the problem.

The problem is that you are removing elements in the list while iterating over it. The indexes are shifted. For example, if you are removing the element at index `i`, the next element has index `i` now. However you do `i+=1` in your loop.

A solution would be to keep a list of elements to remove and remove them at the end, after your loop.

Also:

```
            if Nodelist1[i][1]==Nodelist2[j][1]:
                Nodelist1.remove(Nodelist1[i])
                Nodelist2.remove(Nodelist2[j])  
            else:
                Nodelist1.remove(Nodelist1[i])
                Nodelist2.remove(Nodelist2[j])
```

Both then and else cases are doing the same thing... It makes no sense.

Comment: The problem is if I don't delete it, my Next element will also satisfy the condition i.e ['C', 15] and ['F', 30]