# Remove all occurences of a given value in multiple arrays at once

Tags: python, arrays

I have four arrays, say, A, B, C and D, of the same size NumElements, and I want to remove all the 0s in them. If A has a zero, B, C and D have one too, in the same position. So I was  thinking to loop over the elements of A:

```
for n in range(NumElements):
    if A[n]==0:
       A.pop(n)
       B.pop(n)
       C.pop(n)
       D.pop(n)
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because popping 0s from the arrays reduces their sizes, so I end up trying to access A[NumElements-1], when now A is only NumElements-m long. I know I should work with array copies, but the arrays are quite long and I'd like to keep memory consumption low, since I'm working in a Java virtual machine (don't ask :(((( ). Also, I'd like an approach which is efficient, but most of all readable (this code must be maintained by Python illiterates like me, so I need to KISS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they all have zeros in the same place, then loop over the index *in reverse* and remove that index from each list:

```
for i in reversed(range(NumElements)):
    if not A[i]:
        del A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]
```

By looping over the list in reverse, you keep the indices stable (only elements *past* the current index have been removed, shrinking only the tail of the lists). Since you are not *using* the return value of `list.pop()` (all you get is `0`s anyway, right?), you may as well just use `del` on the list index instead.

I used `reversed(range(NumElements))` here instead of calculating the more strenuous `range(NumElements - 1, -1, -1)`; it is just as efficient but a lot more readable. The [`reversed()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) returns an iterator, handling the reversed number sequence very efficiently. On Python 2, you can do the same with `xrange()`:

```
for i in reversed(xrange(NumElements)):
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0]
>>> B = [2, 4, 0, 10, 9, 0]
>>> C = [5, 3, 0, 10, 8, 0]
>>> D = [10, 3, 0, 1, 34, 0]
>>> for i in reversed(range(NumElements)):
...     if not A[i]:
...         del A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]
... 
>>> A, B, C, D
([1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 10, 9], [5, 3, 10, 8], [10, 3, 1, 34])
```

Comment: +1, nice one, I've forgot about ::-1, using more C# than python at work :)

Comment: @RomanPekar: I stepped away from creating a new list; I like `reversed(range())` better in this case.

Comment: yeah, I see, it was a nice remainder for me anyway

Comment: thanks a lot! It's simple, doesn't make array copies and it's thoroughly explained. Also, I learned about del and xrange, which is an added boon.

Comment: Ah, by the way, I think `if not elem:` is wrong, right? Shouldn't it be `if not A[i]:`?

Answer (score 5):

```
a,b,c,d = [filter(lambda i: i != 0, l) for l in [a,b,c,d]]
```

Filter each list removing elements that are not 0.

Edit,

Just to explain whats happening

Filter takes an expression and "filters" the list, by applying the function to everything in the list, everything that does not return True.

Lambda is a short hand for a function

So

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0
filter(is_even, a)
```

Comment: Very compact! I don't think I'll go for this solution, since I don't know about these `filter` and `lambda` instructions, and the mantainers probably know even less. But it's impressive nonetheless! Shows the power of Python.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do smth like this. I don't know if it's pythonic enough.

```
A = [1, 2, 4, 0]
B = [6, 0, 4, 3, 9]
C = [12, 5, 32, 0, 90]

for row in [A, B, C]:
    for i, v in enumerate(row):
        if v == 0: del row[i]
```

or, if you sure that indexes of zero are equal in all lists:

```
for i in range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1):
    if A[i] == 0:
        for row in [A, B, C]:
             del row[i]
```

Comment: Nice! However, I don't understand why the first form works. I guess this `enumerate` function creates a "static" list of indexes, so from 0 to `NumElements-1`. So, assuming I deleted at least one element, I should get an error when I try to access `A[NumElements-1]`. Isn't that right?

Comment: well I've just found that first one is not working correctly for more than one 0, sorry. you could use `for i, v in reversed(list(enumerate(A))):`, but solution with range is better

Answer (score 2):

Just work from the other end!

```
for n in range(NumElements-1,-1,-1):
    if A[n]==0:
       A.pop(n)
       B.pop(n)
       C.pop(n)
       D.pop(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at my other answer [List accessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704794/list-accessing-in-python/17705123#17705123). You can walk through list `A` and store indexes of 0s in temporary list and then pop them.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a hack but it's simple and it works

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,10,99]
>>> c = [1,87,22]
>>> d = []
>>> d.extend([a,b,c])
>>> to_remove = 1
>>> [i.remove(to_remove) for i in d]
>>> d
[[2, 3], [10, 99], [87, 22]]
```

Note that this will remove all elements marked as to_remove not just zeros at the beginning, I'm assuming this is ok for you because you say that you want to remove all the zeros.

Comment: This won't remove all elements marked as `to_remove`, it'll only remove the first.  Try `a = [1,1,2,3]; b = [1,1,2,3]; c = [1,1,2,3]`, for example.